# Component on Crypton gas analyser circuit board

Tags: identification

This is my first visit to this site. I am no more than an enthusiast in these matters.

My Crypton 307 CO/HC emission module expired in a puff of smoke. The offending part is marked KB LO 2 and + AC -. It is the size of half a thumbnail and has four pins in line on its underside.

[image: Circuit board]

[image: component]

I should be grateful for any information as to what it is and where I might obtain a replacement.

Comment: Uh, that's the rectifier. If that is damaged, probably the rest of your system has gotten overvoltage/overcurrent, too: diodes tend to fail short, and this is just an array of four diodes. Since they didn't fail in exactly the same instant, it's almost certain unrectified current passed through your device, damaging it in multiple places.

Comment: Also, an enthusiast with a crypton gas analyser? Respect! You'd usually only find that on heavy industrial combustion engines.

Comment: @Marcus: I think Crypton is a brand. It's not a krypton (Kr) gas analyser.

Comment: Crypton is correct, its for analysing petrol engines, in this case pre OBD2 systems.

Answer (score 1):

That's a KBL02 bridge rectifier. You can get them at a number of places. [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/KBL02?qs=y841m8McC1Z5v%252BuC10%252BnQQ%3D%3D) has them. You may need to find another supplier if you live in another country. Do a Google search for 'KBL02 Bridge Rectifier' for a list of suppliers...

To answer an unasked question... You might need to find out why the bridge failed. It could have been external (voltage spike, etc. unlikely), old age (components fail on their own sometimes) or some short in the circuit board that the bridge feeds. If the replacement bridge fails (get two- they're cheap) then check the capacitors and other downstream components for shorts. In fact, you could do a quick check (on the DC side) with an ohmmeter before putting in the replacement. If you see a dead short then further investigation will be required.